# What is the best way to display alert message from the MVC4 Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, extjs, response.write

I want to display a message from the controller. I am using MVC4 with Extjs. I tried using:

```
Response.Write(@"<html><body><script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'> Ext.Msg.alert('Notification',' " + message + "')</script></body></html>");
```

But its not working. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can return javaScript alert message from the controller like below

```
return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert(message);</script>");
```

hope this answer helps you..!

Comment: I am not returning anything. It is a simple method

             public void NotifyUser(string message)
             {

     Response.Write(@"<html><body><script language='javascript'         type='text/javascript'> Ext.Msg.alert('Notification',' " + message + "')      </script></body></html>");
                 }